# How can I include hyperlinks in a column in ag-grid with aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

I have this grid:

```
<ag-grid-aurelia #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" 
                             grid-options.bind="filesThatAreMalwareOptions">

                <ag-grid-column header-name="Date" field="date"  width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Filehash" field="fileHash" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Filename" field="fileName" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Filesize" field="fileSize" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Mimetype" field="mimeType" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Malware" field="malware" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
                <ag-grid-column header-name="Virustotal-Link" field="virustotalLink" width.bind="300"></ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-aurelia>
```

And I want the las column Virustotal-Link to be a clickable hyperlink. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. You have do implement a cell-template:

```
<ag-grid-column header-name="Foo" field="foo">
    <ag-cell-template>
        <a href.bind="params.value">${params.value}</a>
    </ag-cell-template>
</ag-grid-column>
```